# Starting service in RHEL7 gives status=1/FAILURE

Tags: python, flask, amazon-ec2, redhat, gunicorn

I am trying to deploy a Flask application in an RHEL 7 EC2 instance. I want to setup the application with Gunicorn and Nginx. I follow [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-serve-flask-applications-with-gunicorn-and-nginx-on-ubuntu-18-04) tutorial. After configuring Gunicorn and starting the service, I am getting a **status=1/FAILURE**. Where am I wrong here? (Please mention if anymore information is needed to identify the issue).

> vectorbot.service

```
[Unit]
Description=Gunicorn instance to serve vectorbot
After=network.target

[Service]
User=ec2-user
Group=ec2-user
WorkingDirectory=/home/ec2-user/projects/vectorbot
Environment="PATH=/home/ec2-user/projects/vectorbot/venv/bin"
ExecStart=/home/ec2-user/projects/vectorbot/venv/bin/gunicorn --workers 3 --bind unix:vectorbot.sock -m 007 wsgi:app

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

> sudo systemctl status -l vectorbot

```
● vectorbot.service - Gunicorn instance to serve vectorbot
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/vectorbot.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2020-03-10 12:52:33 +0530; 10min ago
 Main PID: 9202 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Mar 10 12:52:32 ########.ec2.internal gunicorn[9202]: File "/home/ec2-user/projects/vectorbot/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 393, in stop
Mar 10 12:52:32 ########.ec2.internal gunicorn[9202]: time.sleep(0.1)
Mar 10 12:52:32 ########.ec2.internal gunicorn[9202]: File "/home/ec2-user/projects/vectorbot/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 242, in handle_chld
Mar 10 12:52:32 ########.ec2.internal gunicorn[9202]: self.reap_workers()
Mar 10 12:52:32 ########.ec2.internal gunicorn[9202]: File "/home/ec2-user/projects/vectorbot/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 525, in reap_workers
Mar 10 12:52:32 ########.ec2.internal gunicorn[9202]: raise HaltServer(reason, self.WORKER_BOOT_ERROR)
Mar 10 12:52:32 ########.ec2.internal gunicorn[9202]: gunicorn.errors.HaltServer: <HaltServer 'Worker failed to boot.' 3>
Mar 10 12:52:32 ########.ec2.internal systemd[1]: vectorbot.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Mar 10 12:52:33 ########.ec2.internal systemd[1]: Unit vectorbot.service entered failed state.
Mar 10 12:52:33 ########.ec2.internal systemd[1]: vectorbot.service failed.
```

> journalctl -u vectorbot.service

```
Mar 10 14:11:12 ip-#######.ec2.internal gunicorn[13218]: [2020-03-10 14:11:12 +0530] [13218] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 20.0.4
Mar 10 14:11:12 ip-#######.ec2.internal gunicorn[13218]: [2020-03-10 14:11:12 +0530] [13218] [INFO] Listening at: unix:vectorbot.sock (1321
Mar 10 14:11:12 ip-#######.ec2.internal gunicorn[13218]: [2020-03-10 14:11:12 +0530] [13218] [INFO] Using worker: sync
Mar 10 14:11:12 ip-#######.ec2.internal gunicorn[13218]: [2020-03-10 14:11:12 +0530] [13221] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 13221
Mar 10 14:11:13 ip-#######.ec2.internal gunicorn[13218]: [2020-03-10 14:11:13 +0530] [13222] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 13222
Mar 10 14:11:13 ip-#######.ec2.internal gunicorn[13218]: [2020-03-10 14:11:13 +0530] [13224] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 13224
Mar 10 14:11:13 ip-#######.ec2.internal gunicorn[13218]: [2020-03-10 14:11:13 +0530] [13221] [ERROR] Exception in worker process
Mar 10 14:11:13 ip-#######.ec2.internal gunicorn[13218]: Traceback (most recent call last):
Mar 10 14:11:13 ip-#######.ec2.internal gunicorn[13218]: File "/home/ec2-user/projects/vectorbot/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/
Mar 10 14:11:13 ip-#######.ec2.internal gunicorn[13218]: worker.init_process()
Mar 10 14:11:13 ip-#######.ec2.internal gunicorn[13218]: File "/home/ec2-user/projects/vectorbot/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/
Mar 10 14:11:13 ip-#######.ec2.internal gunicorn[13218]: self.load_wsgi()
Mar 10 14:11:13 ip-#######.ec2.internal gunicorn[13218]: File "/home/ec2-user/projects/vectorbot/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/
Mar 10 14:11:13 ip-#######.ec2.internal gunicorn[13218]: self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
Mar 10 14:11:13 ip-#######.ec2.internal gunicorn[13218]: File "/home/ec2-user/projects/vectorbot/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/
Mar 10 14:11:13 ip-#######.ec2.internal gunicorn[13218]: self.callable = self.load()
Mar 10 14:11:13 ip-#######.ec2.internal gunicorn[13218]: File "/home/ec2-user/projects/vectorbot/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/
Mar 10 14:11:13 ip-#######.ec2.internal gunicorn[13218]: return self.load_wsgiapp()
Mar 10 14:11:13 ip-#######.ec2.internal gunicorn[13218]: File "/home/ec2-user/projects/vectorbot/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/
Mar 10 14:11:13 ip-#######.ec2.internal gunicorn[13218]: return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
Mar 10 14:11:13 ip-#######.ec2.internal gunicorn[13218]: File "/home/ec2-user/projects/vectorbot/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/
Mar 10 14:11:13 ip-#######.ec2.internal gunicorn[13218]: mod = importlib.import_module(module)
Mar 10 14:11:13 ip-#######.ec2.internal gunicorn[13218]: File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
Mar 10 14:11:13 ip-#######.ec2.internal gunicorn[13218]: return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
Mar 10 14:11:13 ip-#######.ec2.internal gunicorn[13218]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
Mar 10 14:11:13 ip-#######.ec2.internal gunicorn[13218]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
Mar 10 14:11:13 ip-#######.ec2.internal gunicorn[13218]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
Mar 10 14:11:13 ip-#######.ec2.internal gunicorn[13218]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
Mar 10 14:11:13 ip-#######.ec2.internal gunicorn[13218]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
Mar 10 14:11:13 ip-#######.ec2.internal gunicorn[13218]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
Mar 10 14:11:13 ip-#######.ec2.internal gunicorn[13218]: File "/home/ec2-user/projects/vectorbot/wsgi.py", line 1, in <module>
Mar 10 14:11:13 ip-#######.ec2.internal gunicorn[13218]: from expose import app
Mar 10 14:11:13 ip-#######.ec2.internal gunicorn[13218]: File "/home/ec2-user/projects/vectorbot/expose.py", line 12, in <module>
Mar 10 14:11:13 ip-#######.ec2.internal gunicorn[13218]: si_data_vec = plyvel.DB('/home/ec2-user/projects/vectorbot/levelDB/si_data_vec', c
Mar 10 14:11:13 ip-#######.ec2.internal gunicorn[13218]: File "plyvel/_plyvel.pyx", line 247, in plyvel._plyvel.DB.__init__
Mar 10 14:11:13 ip-#######.ec2.internal gunicorn[13218]: File "plyvel/_plyvel.pyx", line 88, in plyvel._plyvel.raise_for_status
Mar 10 14:11:13 ip-#######.ec2.internal gunicorn[13218]: plyvel._plyvel.IOError: b'IO error: lock /home/ec2-user/projects/vectorbot/levelDB
Mar 10 14:11:13 ip-#######.ec2.internal gunicorn[13218]: [2020-03-10 14:11:13 +0530] [13221] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 13221)
Mar 10 14:11:14 ip-#######.ec2.internal gunicorn[13218]: [2020-03-10 14:11:14 +0530] [13224] [ERROR] Exception in worker process
Mar 10 14:11:14 ip-#######.ec2.internal gunicorn[13218]: Traceback (most recent call last):
Mar 10 14:11:14 ip-#######.ec2.internal gunicorn[13218]: File "/home/ec2-user/projects/vectorbot/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/
Mar 10 14:11:14 ip-#######.ec2.internal gunicorn[13218]: worker.init_process()
Mar 10 14:11:14 ip-#######.ec2.internal gunicorn[13218]: File "/home/ec2-user/projects/vectorbot/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/
Mar 10 14:11:14 ip-#######.ec2.internal gunicorn[13218]: self.load_wsgi()
Mar 10 14:11:14 ip-#######.ec2.internal gunicorn[13218]: File "/home/ec2-user/projects/vectorbot/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/
Mar 10 14:11:14 ip-#######.ec2.internal gunicorn[13218]: self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
Mar 10 14:11:14 ip-#######.ec2.internal gunicorn[13218]: File "/home/ec2-user/projects/vectorbot/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/
Mar 10 14:11:14 ip-#######.ec2.internal gunicorn[13218]: self.callable = self.load()
Mar 10 14:11:14 ip-#######.ec2.internal gunicorn[13218]: File "/home/ec2-user/projects/vectorbot/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/
Mar 10 14:11:14 ip-#######.ec2.internal gunicorn[13218]: return self.load_wsgiapp()
Mar 10 14:11:14 ip-#######.ec2.internal gunicorn[13218]: File "/home/ec2-user/projects/vectorbot/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/
Mar 10 14:11:14 ip-#######.ec2.internal gunicorn[13218]: return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
Mar 10 14:11:14 ip-#######.ec2.internal gunicorn[13218]: File "/home/ec2-user/projects/vectorbot/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/
Mar 10 14:11:14 ip-#######.ec2.internal gunicorn[13218]: mod = importlib.import_module(module)
Mar 10 14:11:14 ip-#######.ec2.internal gunicorn[13218]: File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
Mar 10 14:11:14 ip-#######.ec2.internal gunicorn[13218]: return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
Mar 10 14:11:14 ip-#######.ec2.internal gunicorn[13218]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
Mar 10 14:11:14 ip-#######.ec2.internal gunicorn[13218]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
Mar 10 14:11:14 ip-#######.ec2.internal gunicorn[13218]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
Mar 10 14:11:14 ip-#######.ec2.internal gunicorn[13218]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
Mar 10 14:11:14 ip-#######.ec2.internal gunicorn[13218]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
Mar 10 14:11:14 ip-#######.ec2.internal gunicorn[13218]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
Mar 10 14:11:14 ip-#######.ec2.internal gunicorn[13218]: File "/home/ec2-user/projects/vectorbot/wsgi.py", line 1, in <module>
Mar 10 14:11:14 ip-#######.ec2.internal gunicorn[13218]: from expose import app
Mar 10 14:11:14 ip-#######.ec2.internal gunicorn[13218]: File "/home/ec2-user/projects/vectorbot/expose.py", line 12, in <module>
Mar 10 14:11:14 ip-#######.ec2.internal gunicorn[13218]: si_data_vec = plyvel.DB('/home/ec2-user/projects/vectorbot/levelDB/si_data_vec', c
Mar 10 14:11:14 ip-#######.ec2.internal gunicorn[13218]: File "plyvel/_plyvel.pyx", line 247, in plyvel._plyvel.DB.__init__
Mar 10 14:11:14 ip-#######.ec2.internal gunicorn[13218]: File "plyvel/_plyvel.pyx", line 88, in plyvel._plyvel.raise_for_status
Mar 10 14:11:14 ip-#######.ec2.internal gunicorn[13218]: plyvel._plyvel.IOError: b'IO error: lock /home/ec2-user/projects/vectorbot/levelDB
Mar 10 14:11:14 ip-#######.ec2.internal gunicorn[13218]: [2020-03-10 14:11:14 +0530] [13224] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 13224)
Mar 10 14:11:14 ip-#######.ec2.internal gunicorn[13218]: [2020-03-10 14:11:14 +0530] [13222] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 13222)
Mar 10 14:11:15 ip-#######.ec2.internal gunicorn[13218]: [2020-03-10 14:11:15 +0530] [13218] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
Mar 10 14:11:15 ip-#######.ec2.internal gunicorn[13218]: [2020-03-10 14:11:15 +0530] [13218] [INFO] Reason: Worker failed to boot.
Mar 10 14:11:15 ip-#######.ec2.internal systemd[1]: vectorbot.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=3/NOTIMPLEMENTED
Mar 10 14:11:15 ip-#######.ec2.internal systemd[1]: Unit vectorbot.service entered failed state.
Mar 10 14:11:15 ip-#######.ec2.internal systemd[1]: vectorbot.service failed.
```

Comment: The line `Environment="PATH=..."` looks wrong to me, if you don't have the standard directories such as `/usr/bin` or `/bin` in `$PATH`, you won't be able to execute external commands... Having said that, not sure whether that's what's causing the problem here...

Comment: Get more logs with `journalctl -u vectorbot.service`, that should give you a complete exception stack, which should tell you where things went wrong.

Comment: @filbranden I have updated the question with the logs you mentioned. Please see whether you can find the issue.

Comment: From the logs I identified the error was because of plyvel.DB. Not Gunicorn configs.

Comment: https://github.com/wbolster/plyvel/issues/13#issuecomment-21276495 Do you have more than one process accessing the database at a time, or an issue with cleaning up the connection?

Comment: @Jon only one process is accessing the database.